# AWS ALB not receiving all traffic from VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer, vpc

I have an AWS Application Load Balancer sitting in front of my EC2 instances.

I'm investigating an intermittent problem where it seems some requests are not getting through to my application. The application is an integration engine so I can see a queue of messages as they come in. Occasionally we are missing a message in the queue that we are expecting from the source.

At some point in the transmission it appears the whole request is getting dropped. This happens too often to just be random internet connectivity issues. I decided to pull out the logs for both the [ALB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html) and the [VPC flow logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html) to compare.

I noticed a discrepancy where I can see traffic in VPC Flow Logs with the destination being my ALB, but these do not correlate with ALB logs, that traffic doesn't exist in the ALB logs.

I'm also aware there is an ACTION column in the VPC Flow logs for determining whether it was Rejected or Accepted (based on security groups etc.) and they all say ACCEPT.

Is there any other reason why traffic might be getting stopped somewhere in the VPC before reaching the ALB? Do I have a misunderstanding about what's in the VPC Flow logs?

I've tried sending a selection of HTTP requests to my ALB endpoint. I can see majority make it through to the application fine, however occasionally one goes missing. Retrying the missing messages succeeds so have eliminated prospect of it being a problem with request content.

I have tried examining the VPC Flow Logs and the ALB logs to determine where the message may have gone missing. While it's quite hard to correlate exactly in the logs, as an illustrative example, if I send 10 HTTP requests and 1 goes missing, I would see the 10 requests in the VPC Flow logs but only 9 in the ALB logs.

Comment: Looks like you have done a deep dive (nice!) and it may now be time for an AWS support ticket, I'd say.